# How do you write the uniqueness symbol in cplex?

Tags: unique, symbols, cplex

I have to write this forall:

forall (m in M: (both single m and only one chosen))

How is the symbol of mathematical uniqueness implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute card before the subject to block.

```
range r=1..2;
{int} M[r]=[{1,2},{3}];

int cards[i in r]=card(M[i]);

dvar int x;

subject to
{
  forall(i in r) forall(m in M[i]:cards[i]==1) x==m;
}
```

gives

```
x==3
```